# The imported api names recognized by ida are inconsistent

Tags: c++, dll, ida

I analyzed two samples, they both import the `gethostname` function of `ws2_32`, but in the .idata segment, ida recognizes it as the correct `gethostname` and `__imp__gethostname` respectively.

[image]
[image]

I used `dumpbin /imports` to view the import tables of the two samples respectively, and found that they both only show the API's ordinal number.

```
WS2_32.dll
            409188 Import Address Table
            40955C Import Name Table
                 0 time date stamp
                 0 Index of first forwarder reference

                  Ordinal    12
                  Ordinal    52
                  Ordinal    57
                  Ordinal    15
                  Ordinal   115

WININET.dll
            40915C Import Address Table
            409530 Import Name Table
                 0 time date stamp
                 0 Index of first forwarder reference

               56 InternetCloseHandle
               75 InternetQueryOptionA
               6F InternetOpenA
               49 HttpSendRequestA
```

my questions are:

1. Why does ida get two different names when their import table is the same?
2. I found that except ws2_32, other dll import functions have no ordinal number, but function names. What caused this difference?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: As a developer you can decide if you import a DLL function by it's ordinal or by it's name. Which version of IDA do you use? BTW: please don't post text output like dumpbin output as screenshot. Just copy and paste the text and format it as code to preserver formatting.

Comment: @Robert, After testing, I found that if I call the DLL function by it's ordinal, then it will not appear in the import table (I'm using GetProcAddress(hDLL, ord) to do it, is this right? ). And the version of ida is 7.5. In addition, the output of dumpbin has been modified to be in code format, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Using `GetprocAddress` is a totally different way of loading DLL function. You can use it for ordinals but also for named functions but on both cases the used function(s) will never be visible in import section.

Comment: Is there a way to use the ordinal and have it appear in the import table, Like the sample in the question? Maybe the question is a bit silly, but I haven't found the answer yet...

Comment: I not an C++ expert so I don't know how to import a DLL function by ordinal but I know it from other programming languages (and if other languages can do so C/C++ can do it for sure, too).